# Comparing images with OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I'm trying to monitor a LCD reading using OpenCV (and picamera).
I'm taking a reading about every second and I wish that the image is the same for at least three frames (3 seconds). Just to avoid scenarios where I would analyse the image when there is a light switch or something is interrupting the image.

So I read three images in a row and compute the difference between them by printing (img0, img1, img2 are three grayscaled consecutive images):

```
> print(max(diff(img0,img1), diff(img1,img2), diff(img0, img2)))
```

where

```
> def diff(image1, image2):
>     return abs(image1-image2).mean()
```

I've also used **absdiff** function with similar results.
But it's strange that when there is no image change (visible to me), the values are around 120-160. But when I turn off the lights, the value drops to 110 and then rises to 220. And when I stick a finger to the frame, the value can still be in the 120-160 area. I can't figure out a real pattern that would make a lot of sense. Perhaps the problem is that there is shaking and a lot of per-pixel differences that add up.
Is there a smarter way to do this?
I'm attaching some sample pictures.
[image: frame 1]

[image: frame 2]

[image: frame 3]

Comment: Use `cv2.absdiff(img1, img2)`. Possible duplicate of [CV - Extract differences between two images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27035672/cv-extract-differences-between-two-images)

Answer (score 2):

This issue is likely caused because you're subtracting images with type `uint8`.  Any negative numbers will wrap up to be high values.  For example,

```
> np.array([-3,-2,-1,0], dtype=np.uint8)
[253 254 255 0]
```

So any pixels where `image2` is greater than `image1` in the `diff` function will register has high values.  You can first change them to type float.  Using your first two sample images:

```
> print(diff(img0, img1))
209.93
> img0 = img0.astype(float)
> img1 = img1.astype(float)
> print(diff(img0, img1))
3.85
```