# Is there a way to use imagemaps in python?

Tags: python, html, xml, coordinates, imagemap

Im trying to get the coordinates of different polygonal shapes in an image to process them in python. 
Is there a way to get something like html imagemaps and process it in python?

To be more specific: I want to check if a certain area in an image changed - the areas are polygonal.

Is there a way to maybe convert html imagemaps to make it usable in python? 
Or is there a tool to create such imagemaps?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27035672/cv-extract-differences-between-two-images) answer your question?

Comment: @Torxed thanks for the suggestion. I already tried it like that. The images I use have slight changes in lighting. The process mentioned above seems to be "too precise" for my problem.