# how to finding difference between images using Java with OpenCV or another API

Tags: java, opencv

I have gone through below URLs to identify the difference between the two images. But I need the same functionalities in java with OpenCV or another API. Anybody can help me?
https://codedeepai.com/finding-difference-between-multiple-images-using-opencv-and-python/

[CV - Extract differences between two images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27035672/cv-extract-differences-between-two-images/47938979#47938979)

Comment: May I suggest that you google "java opencv image difference"? I got a lot of results, including several questions here.

Comment: https://en.lmgtfy.app/?q=java+opencv+image+difference&iie=1

Comment: Add sample code

Comment: Perhaps post example images. Have you tried cv2.matchTemplate()