# Get difference between two images

Tags: image, image-processing, imagemagick

I have the following issue. I have two images. Image 2 is basically Image 1 with an overlay. It's something that we added using a darkening blend-mode. The images are just grayscale images btw.

Now I'd like to create an new image, that contains only the difference between image 1 and 2. So a transparent png that if I just lay it over Image 1 without any blend mode, I'd have the same result as looking at image 2.

This is Image 1:

[image: Image1]

And this is Image 2:

[image: Image2]

I already played around a little bit with imagemagicks compare, but maybe I was missing the correct parameters, but I didn't get the result I am looking for...

The solution would need to be something that we can automate. So imagemagick would be awesome!

Comment: you can treat the images as matrices, just calculate the diference between them: img3 = img1 - img2. 
then you can recover: img1 = img3 + img2
also, take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27035672/cv-extract-differences-between-two-images

Answer (score 0):

i don't know a lot about imagemagicks.
however, there is a python library that is super-simple to understand and implement for your wishes: [pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html)

you can :

- import the Image package : `from PIL import Image`
- upload images : `img = Image.open("image.png")` (works with a lot of file formats)
- read its dimensions : `width, height = img.size`
- read its pixels : `color = img.getpixel((x, y))` (returns `(r, g, b, a)`)
- etc...

you can even generate a new image from this matrix and save it in OS...
so with a bit of manipulation, getting the difference of pixels between two images should not be too difficult...
hope it helped :)
kyros